# "Skipping incompatible" on Blue Gene machine

Tags: architecture, compiler-construction, compatibility, powerpc, kyotocabinet

I'm trying to build Google Protocolbuffers and Kyotocabinet on a Blue Gene supercomputer, which is a PowerPC64 based machine, running Suse Linux, gcc 4.1.2.

When I compile my code, both Google Protocolbuffers and Kyotocabinet gave "skipping incompatible" error.
Compile command line:

`g++ -g -Xlinker -zmuldefs -I/some_path/include $sourceFile -o $fileName -L/some_path/lib -lkyotocabinet -lz -lstdc++ -lrt -lpthread -lm -lc -lprotobuf -lprotoc meta.pb.cc`

Then I changed installation of them, by using `./configure --host=powerpc-bgp-linux`, Google Protocolbuffers works this time, but Kyotocabinet still give that error as below:

`/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /some_path/lib/libkyotocabinet.so when searching for -lkyotocabinet

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /some_path/lib/libkyotocabinet.a when searching for -lkyotocabinet

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkyotocabinet

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

I checked `config.status` of them, Google Protocolbuffers has some thing like this

`sys_lib_search_path_spec='/usr/lib/gcc/powerpc64-suse-linux/4.1.2 /usr/powerpc64-suse-linux/lib /usr/lib /lib'`

Apparently it know how to find proper stuff to use. But Kyotocabinet doesn't have this kind of settings in config.status. Hope this tip will help.

Is there any solution so I can use Kyotocabinet on BlueGene? Or can I add some lines like mentioned above to tell Kyotocabinet where to find correct lib? Or could you recommend some fast key-value stores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not in finding Kyotocabinet. Your problem is that the library you are pointing at: `/some_path/lib/libkyotocabinet.so` is built for incompatible architecture (most linkely `ppc32`).

Do `file -L /some_path/lib/libkyotocabinet.so` and see what it says. You *must* rebuilt it for the same architecture as what `gcc` produces by default.

Update: `file` says `ELF 64-bit MSB shared object, 64-bit PowerPC`. But does that match what your `g++` outputs by default? What is the output from:

```
echo "int foo() { return 0; }" | g++ -xc++ - -c -o foo.o &&
file foo.o
```

I bet above will print `32-bit PowerPC`, in which case you need to add `-m64` to your command line.

Update 2:

> Any idea for this problem??

You should not be so helpless. You understand that the problem is mis-matched libraries, so go and *fix* it.

1. Decide whether you want the final binary to run in 32-bit or 64-bit mode
2. Obtain or rebuild all the libraries your need in the bitness you desire
3. Build the final binary
4. Profit!

Comment: It said libkyotocabinet.so: symbolic link to `libkyotocabinet.so.10.4.0'. any clue?

Comment: @Tony: if it is a symbolic link check again the file where it is pointing at (i.e. file libkyotocabinet.so.10.4.0).

Comment: libkyotocabinet.so.10.4.0: ELF 64-bit MSB shared object, 64-bit PowerPC or cisco 7500, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped. Seems like it did find correct architecture.

Comment: @Employed Russian: yes you were right. foo.o: ELF 32-bit MSB relocatable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version 1 (SYSV). I add -m64 then Kyotocabinet works, I'm moving forward. But since then Google protocolbuffers stopped working and give "skipping incompatible".  I checked the libprotobuf.so.6.0.0 with file, it was ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, PowerPC or cisco 4500, I tried give -m64 option to according to the configure help, when making it, gives error :/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/powerpc64-suse-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib/libz.so when searching for -lz

Comment: Continued...  /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/powerpc64-suse-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib/libz.a when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libz.so when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libz.a when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/powerpc64-suse-linux/4.1.2/../../../libz.so when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/powerpc64-suse-linux/4.1.2/../../../libz.a when searching for -lz

Comment: @Employed Russian, thanks for your patience, finally I got Google protocol buffers and Kyotocabinet on the same version 64bit. The final binary too. Thank you very much!